# Unable to Instantiate this Delegate Using Reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, avaloniaui

I need to pass a specific delegate as a parameter to a [method of which I can't change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.addhook?view=netcore-3.1). The delegate is '[System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.hwndsourcehook?view=netcore-3.1)' which is part of PresentationCore.dll. It has to be that delegate, it cannot be a generic delegate with the same signature. And AFIAK you can't cast delegates from one type to another.

This is the method for the delegate:

```
public IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (condition) {// Do stuff };
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Everything works fine when the assembly is loaded at compile time. However I'm porting the project to the Avalonia framework and this particular assembly must be loaded at runtime, so I have to use reflection.

I thought this should work...

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Temp\PresentationCore.dll");
Type hwndSourceHookDelegateType = dll.GetType("System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceHook"); 
MethodInfo wndProc = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(nameof(this.WndProc));
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(hwndSourceHookDelegateType, wndProc)
```

... but the last line throws:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the target method because
>   its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.'

Even though the signature is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method isn't a static method, so you need to use:

```
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(hwndSourceHookDelegateType, this, wndProc);
```

or

```
IntPtr del = (IntPtr) Delegate.CreateDelegate(hwndSourceHookDelegateType, this, wndProc);
```

Passing "this" to the second argument will allow the method to be bound to the instance method on the current object